# Rcpp implicit construction of DataFrame from S4 slot

Tags: r, rcpp, r-s4

`Rcpp::DataFrame pData =pheno.slot("data")`

This fails on clang++ but succeeds with g++

```
error: conversion from 'Rcpp::SlotProxyPolicy<Rcpp::S4_Impl<PreserveStorage> >::SlotProxy' to 'Rcpp::DataFrame' (aka 'DataFrame_Impl<PreserveStorage>') is ambiguous
            Rcpp::DataFrame fsdata = fspd.slot("data");
                            ^        ˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜
```

Comment: If you want to submit a bug report, this is where: https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues

Comment: And if you want to work around it -- explicitly wrap the slot, e.g. `Rcpp::DataFrame fsdata = wrap(fspd.slot("data"));`. Or `Rcpp::DataFrame fsdata = static_cast<DataFrame>(fspd.slot("data"));`.

Comment: I did this `Rcpp::RObject fspdObj = fspd.slot("data");Rcpp::DataFrame fsdata = Rcpp::DataFrame(fspdObj.get__());` and it worked, which may essentially the same as what @KevinUshey suggested.